# Show controls on a Audio() object created in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an Audio() object created in javascript like this: 
`const audio = new Audio();`
After giving it the atributes like `.source` and `audio.controls = true` I couldn't find the controls in my page. 
What I want to do is show the controls of that audio on a `<div>` in the HTML

Comment: So you need to show the code that you have used to insert the audio into the DOM. When you create any HTML element in Javascript, you then need to find the div, say by using getElementById, then append the audio to the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you did but setting the `controls` to `true` shows the element in the document.

[An image showing the audio controls working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieUaW.png)

If someone else has a similar problem, try inspecting in the hierarchy if one of the ancestors is hidden.

https://codepen.io/blfunex/pen/ZELRQbL